# Filling Map<> using Java8 style

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I like the functional style. So would like to convert `String` to `Map<Position, Character>` using Java-8(If it's possible done in java-8). Where:

- ***key*** should be character `Position`,
- ***value*** should be `Character`'s ignore white spaces.

```
String str = "a b c\nc d e\na b c"; // note \n (new line) 

Map<Position, Character> map;
     // key     value
     // (0,0)   'a'
     // (0,1)   'b' <= skip spaces
     // (0,2)   'c'
     // (1,0)   'c' <= reset at new line
     // ...
     // (2,2)   'c'
```

So far I came up with smth like this(probably it's all wrong):

```
map = str.chars()
         .filter(ch -> ch != ' ')
         .reduce((Map<Position, Character> m, int ch) -> {
             // put magic here. 
             m.put(new Position(x, y), ch);
         });
```

Sorry if a similar question was asked, but my 1h searching didn't give me clear enough answer.

Comment: Why would you want to use a functional style when it appears a procedural style is going to be superior?

Comment: In functional style?? I like it. I like the look. and I think It easier to read. plus I want to learn new stuff.

Comment: You might want to look at `Collectors.toMap()`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you looking for someone to [write this code for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108551/347499)? Or do you have a specific question that you could elaborate on? The code you're showing doesn't compile, so it's obviously not good, but I don't see a specific programming question here.

Comment: By "functional style" it appears that you mean *Streams*, because otherwise you could do this using a recursive function, which is also "functional style". Streams is not the right tool for the job. It is not the answer to everything, so please don't try to force it to be. To steal a related [quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski): *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use Streams." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: @4castle I didn't want to make you or anyone angry. Engish Is not my native language, so probably I didn't words right. I'm doing some challenge. And had Idea to use streams for this method. More challenge( I'm sure I can do it in a procedural style). I did successfully use streams in some other methods. But this one... I'm just stuck. probably because of here so late (1am...)

Comment: @my- I promise, I'm not angry at all :) Your English is really good in this question. I'm just trying to help guide you into writing a clear question.

Comment: @Andreas Probably it's the reason why I couldn't find any info pointing me the right direction. btw I like the quote.

Comment: @4castle I know the title is bad. Any suggestions to better one? I could not come up with short enough and be easy to understand what I asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
Map<Integer, Char> stringMap = IntStream.range(0, str.length()).filter(x -> ! str[x].equals(' ')).collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, y -> str[y]) 
// Code should be something like this. Not sure it compiles as is
```

My java is a little rusty but I think that syntax still works.

I am a little concerned why you would do this though and not use `String::charAt`. Are you looking for mutability? Java Strings are pretty optimized for memory efficiency

Comment: Position class has x & y.  Not single Integer.  y should be updated then the new line appears.

Comment: Ah well then you are carrying y between iterations and this is therefore not a good case for streams. Streams are cool for some things but if you have to carry and change state between iterations then you are not in streams wheelhouse any more.

Comment: As I wrote at the end of the post is what I came with after googling. I'm new to java8. I had feeling solution Involves `IntStream`'s. But couldn't wrap my head around how to put all together. I don't need mutability ( map's only value will be mutated, key and size will stay the same).

Comment: @my- I understand that but that violates an underlying part of streams. Part of running a lambda is that it should not matter what order lambdas are run in and there should be no state shared between lambdas. A counter or a knowledge of how many of a character are seen would be example of shared state between lambdas